# How to add parameters Activity by JavaPoet?

Tags: android, android-activity, javapoet

I want to generate code like

```
public void inject(MainActivity activity){
  ......
}
```

by JavaPoet in javaLibrary ,I add the code in AbstractProcess.process(...) like:

```
MethodSpec methodSpec = MethodSpec.methodBuilder("inject")
                .addModifiers(Modifier.PUBLIC)

       .addParameter(Class.forName(element.getQualifiedName().toString()), "activity")
                .returns(void.class)
                //.addStatement()
                .build();
```

then I got the exception `ClassNotFoundExeption` when I build project.How shoud I addParameter MainActivity? Thank you!

Comment: Normally you do this by using ClassName.get(MainActivity.class). Or use ClassName.get(typeElement), where typeElement represents MainActivity (in your case).

Comment: Thank you for your answer !  MainActivity  is unreachable in my javaLibrary,How shoud I do ? Thank you !

Comment: What do you mean with 'unreachable'?

Comment: It's mean  MainActivity is the class in Android app moudle ,it cant find in java Library,How shoud I do to get the ManActivity class in my library? Thank you !

Comment: You can also use: ClassName.get(packageNameString, classNameString). But, at least, when you are running your code, the class must be inside your class path.

Comment: Okay, I'll try. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can send a String param that represents the qualified name of your class, in combo with the static method `bestGuess` of the `ClassName` class.

```
MethodSpec methodSpec = MethodSpec.methodBuilder("inject")
   .addModifiers(Modifier.PUBLIC)
   .addParameter(ClassName.bestGuess("qualified.name.of.your.Class"), "activity")
            .returns(void.class) //you can delete this, javapoet uses this as default
            //.addStatement(....code...)
            .build();
```